# Ошибка при sudo apt update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: Как исправить?[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3y80.png)

При попытке обновить происходит ошибка

Comment: Попробуй селать бекап файла `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnedev.list/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnedev.list.bak`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса